# How do you make a popup menu on a ListView item?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

How do you make a menu popup appear when you click a listview item, and have the menu popup under the item that you clicked?

Is it possible to do this using the ListView.ItemClick event to do this?

This question is for api 22+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been many answers for this question but all that I have found are on old APIs, so this is how I did it.

It is possible to do it using the ListView.ItemClick event, and achieve a menu as shown.

(Names deleted)

[image: Menu Example]

```
[Activity(Label = "Employee Management", Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Material")]
public class EmpMgmtActivity : Activity
{
    ListView empListView;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.EmpMgmtLayout);

        empListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.EmpMgmtList);

        GenerateEmpList(EmployeeStorage.employeeList);

        empListView.ItemClick += EmpListView_ItemClick;
    }

    private void EmpListView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var menu = new PopupMenu(this, empListView.GetChildAt(e.Position));
        menu.Inflate(Resource.Layout.popup_menu);
        menu.MenuItemClick += (s, a) =>
        {
            switch (a.Item.ItemId)
            {
                case Resource.Id.pop_button1:
                    // update stuff
                    break;
                case Resource.Id.pop_button2:
                    // delete stuff
                    break;
            }
        };
        menu.Show();
    }
```

Most of this information is fairly easy to find, the part I had trouble with isnt getting the menu to popup but to have it popup on the right line item.  The key for me was to lookup the individual view from the list.

```
var menu = new PopupMenu(this, empListView.GetChildAt(e.Position));
```

If you use 
    (View)Sender
Which comes in the even args, it will place the menu near the top of the page, which is not ideal.

Therefore using 
    ListView.GetChildAt(e.Position)
Which returns the actual view of the list item, you can have the menu popup in the correct location.

XML Code for the popup menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/pop_button1" android:title="Edit Employee" showAsAction="always" />
<item android:id="@+id/pop_button2" android:title="Delete Employee" showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Hope this helps!